# how to debug form rendering issues when using angular-schema-form

Tags: angular-schema-form

i am using angular-schema-form to render some forms dynamically. the forms are rendering mostly as expected, but when i use tabs, only the tab names are getting rendered, but not the content of the tabs. i have tested the json schema and the form on the schemaform.io test page (http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html) where it renders correctly, but the same doesn't render the tab content in my application.

Note 1: it is worthwhile to note that i am using angular-schema-form within a larger application that is based on spring-boot + angularjs (the application itself is generated using JHipster (https://jhipster.github.io)

any pointers on where i need to start looking for debugging this issue? i looked at the google chrome developer tools but did not find anything useful to help debug.

Note 2: i am not using any custom decorators or validators. both the schema and form are generated from a YAML template which is more 'user friendly'

Comment: If you inspect the generated source are they the same for both? I assume from what you have written that there may be a CSS conflict so you could start comparing the CSS on the items in the tabs in both versions and see where the styles are coming from.

Comment: Could you share an example of the YAML template that you're generating the schema and form from?

Comment: seems i cannot get SO's code formatting syntax... so here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nagarajasr/d987648b5106b5d54c0405c1b766fdf0)